# Tilde/Backtick button not working on Windows 10

Tags: keyboard, windows-10, keyboard-layout

I've recently upgraded to Window 10, and ever since then my backtick is not working. It's a keyboard with a US layout, and in my language settings this seems to be properly set up. When I switch to another layout (I used German for testing), the (physical) button is working. So the keyboard itself is fine.

Here are some pictures for reference:

## Settings

[image: language settings]
[image: Input method]

## Keyboard

[image: keyboard photo]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Update (2018-07-05):** Recent versions of Windows 10 may have changed the location of the settings menu. See [the answer of @Wingu](https://superuser.com/a/1336774/7444) for an alternative.

---

I finally figured it out. The problem is that the Windows language switcher uses the tilde to switch between layouts. To fix this, go to *Advanced Language Settings* in the Control Panel:

[image: Advanced Language Settings]

Click on "Change Language Bar Hotkeys", which opens up the following dialog:

[image: Advanced Key Settings]

Here, click on "Change Key Sequence", and on the following dialog change the assignment away from the tilde/grave accent key. Or simply unassign it.

[image: Final Dialog]

Comment: Awesome, thanks for figuring this out! Hard to believe you and I are the only ones having this problem?!

Comment: I believe this is only a problem when you are using an input language with multiple layouts? Maybe? I also installed a Japanese IME a while back which needs a switcher for Hiragana, Katakana and Kanji. My wild guess is that this is why it got borked. Just a wild guess though. But yes, it seems like it's a fairly uncommon problem. Glad I was able to help though :)

Comment: I had this problem with US international layout and Thai. I was really desperate because it makes it almost impossible to write markdown documentation with embedded code.

Comment: Just logged in here to say thank you! this is my problem since May this year! I did so many tricks but this one is a life saver :) Good job mate!

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem, but I'm upvoting because I didn't know that backtick can be used there (already unassigned both sequences long time ago).

Comment: I can confirm this occurs when language support for English (US) and Thai Kedmanee Keyboard is installed.The system was upgraded from Windows 8 to Windows 10 and I guess the setting had changed to not all that sensible default.

Comment: why windows control panel is so inconsistent, jeez microsoft

Comment: For Windows 11: Settings > Time & language > Typing > Advanced keyboard settings > Input language hot keys

Answer (score 8):

I have Windows 10 yet I cannot find *Advanced Language Settings* in the Control Panel so to the others who have the same problem, heres how I found it and follow the instructions by **exhuma**!

**Open Windows Settings** and search for *Region and language settings*

In **related settings**, you will find **Advanced Keyboard Settings**

In Switching input methods, you will find **Language bar options**

Then **continue to proceed with exhuma's instructions** after the first image included.

Comment: Thanks for noticing this. I've added a link to this answer to my original answer so you are properly credited and have a chance to get upvotes. Credit where credit is due! ;)

Answer (score 2):

I experienced a similar issue with the backtick key not working directly -- on the second keypress, it would type two backticks. This was interfering with my use of Ctrl-` as a shortcut in my IDE.

The solution I found was to change Language Setting to English (United States), to use the 'US Keyboard' settings.

[image: Windows Language Settings page]

As a side note, I would tend to observe that Windows 10's Settings UI -- being a mixture of new pages, links to older dialogs, and Control Panel -- is a sodden mush of dog's breakfast which makes most tasks harder & more confusing rather than clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Found faster way for windows 10 (20190417) :

Search for "Language Bar Options" then follow the "Change Key Sequence" instructions posted by exhuma : https://superuser.com/posts/1003913/revisions

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Where exactly do you search? In the start menu? Which build number of Windows is this? The value you specify `20190417` does not seem like a build number. Can you add these details? If I am able to reproduce it I will add it to my updates and redirect people to this answer as well.